# RoadId() from the BaseWaveApplLayer.cc (VEINS, OMNET++)

Tags: omnet++

how can i get information such as roadid in order to use it as a new field for example in beacon messages from BaseWaveApplLayer.cc?

best,
Pavlos

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the class [`TraCICommandInterface`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h) which provides access methods for such data like `getRoadId()`.

In the class [`TraCIDemo11p`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc) you can find an example how to get this information. It basically boilds down to performing the following steps:

```
TraCIMobility* mobility = TraCIMobilityAccess().get(getParentModule());
TraCICommandInterface* traci = mobility->getCommandInterface();
TraCICommandInterface::Vehicle* traciVehicle = mobility->getVehicleCommandInterface();
traciVehicle->getRoadId();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, i had an older version of VEINS, now i use the latest, all works fine.

best,