# Error while accessing Mobility module at the MAC layer of Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

In VEINS 4.4, one can access the current location of the vehicles at the application layer (e.g. *TraCIDemo11p*) via "Mobility" module which is defined through *TraCIMobility*.

I followed the same approach to access the Mobility module at the lower layer (*MAC1609_4.cc*), where I added following statement at the stage 0 of the initialize function:

```
TraCIMobility* mobility = TraCIMobilityAccess().get(getParentModule());
```

However, I am not getting any compilation error, but when OMNET throws errors when the simulation starts and it gives following error.

> Error in Module (MAC1609_4)
>   RSUExampleScenario.node[0].nic.mac1609_4(id=12) at event # 2, t = 0.1:
>   Assert: condition traci false in function get,
>   \veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIMobility.h line 193

I have searched around for different possible solutions, but, I am still unable to solve this problem.

Related posts are:

[How to access TraCI command interface from TraCIDemoRSU11p in Veins Car2X simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35790944/how-to-access-traci-command-interface-from-tracidemorsu11p-in-veins-car2x-simula?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Transmission of vehicular status in Veins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667465/transmission-of-vehicular-status-in-veins)

[RoadId() from the BaseWaveApplLayer.cc (VEINS, OMNET++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915258/roadid-from-the-basewaveappllayer-cc-veins-omnet?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How to get Coordinates of each vehicle in VEINS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49876694/how-to-get-coordinates-of-each-vehicle-in-veins)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a *TraCIMobility* sub-module in the parent module of the *Mac1609_4*. This, however, is not the *Car* but the *Nic80211p*, which has no such sub-module, hence, the failing assertion.

It should work when you go up one additional layer in the hierarchy, as you then use the *Car* module as root to find the corresponding sub-module:

```
TraCIMobility* mobility = TraCIMobilityAccess().get(getParentModule()->getParentModule());
```

See the *Car* module and the *Nic80211p* module for reference:

- https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/src/veins/nodes/Car.ned
- https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/src/veins/modules/nic/Nic80211p.ned

Comment: Dear Julian, 
Thank you so much for your response and clarifying the issue. I now understand your point and the error. 

This means that we can only access the mobility module at the higher layers  (specifically at App layer) only then ??

Comment: No. It means that you should add another call to `getParentModule()` to your expression, as shown in the code above.